# Can I decompose this matrix into separate parts?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, block-matrices

Right now I have a matrix of the form

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & (a^\top b) ~ b ~c^\top \\
c ~ b^\top (b^\top a) & 0, 
\end{pmatrix}

where $a$ and $b$ are vectors of the same dimension, and $c$ is another vector of arbitrary dimension. The bottom left submatrix is the transpose of the upper right submatrix.  Is there any way to disentangle the variables here so that I get something, for example, of the  following form $$M_1(a) \, M_2(b) \, M_3(c)$$ where $M_1(a)$ is a matrix that just contains $a$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't see a way to decompose this into the form you suggest I was able to decompose the matrix to a similar form.

First, suppose $a$ and $b$ are $n$-dimensional column vectors and $c$ is an $m$-dimensional column vector. We can reorganize the expressions to

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
0_{n x n} & (a^\top b)b c^\top \\
c b^\top (b^\top a) & 0_{m x m}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0_{n x n} & b a^Tbc^T \\
c b^T a b^T & 0_{m x m}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

which can be decomposed into

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{n \times n} & 0_{n \times 1} \\ 0_{m \times n} & c
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0_{n \times n} & b \\ b^\top & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0_{n \times n} & a \\ a^\top & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0_{n \times n} & b \\ b^\top & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_{n \times n} & 0_{n \times m} \\ 0_{1\times n} & c^\top
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't a fully rigorous non-existence proof, this argument suggests that no such decomposition exists for $n \times n$ matrices for $n>2$.

It is easy to check that $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & a^\intercal b b c^\intercal\\ cb^\intercal b^\intercal a & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a^\intercal \\ c& 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & b^\intercal b^\intercal\\ b b & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & c^\intercal\\ a & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$ Now suppose that the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & c^\intercal\\ a & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has some decomposition $M(a)*M(c)$. I.e., for any two $n\times n$ matrices $a$ and $c$, we can find scalars $j_1,\dots, j_8, k_1, \dots, k_8$ such that for the matrices $$M(a)=\begin{bmatrix} j_1a+j_2a^\intercal & j_3a+j_4a^\intercal\\ j_5a+j_6a^\intercal & j_7a+j_8a^\intercal \end{bmatrix}, \\ M(c)=\begin{bmatrix} k_1c+k_2c^\intercal & k_3c+k_4c^\intercal\\ k_5c+k_6c^\intercal & k_7c+k_8c^\intercal \end{bmatrix},$$ we have $M(a)*M(c) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & c^\intercal\\ a & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$ Then, $$(j_1k_3+j_3k_7)ac+(j_1k_4+j_3k_8)ac^\intercal+(j_2k_3+j_4k_7)a^\intercal c+(j_2k_4+j_4k_8)a^\intercal c^\intercal = c^\intercal.$$ Now, let $V$ be the vector space of $n \times n$ matrices, and observe that $\dim(\text{span}\{ac, ac^\intercal, a^\intercal c, a^\intercal c^\intercal\}) \leq 4$ and $\dim(V)=n^2.$ Since $a$ and $c$ are arbitrary, the product $M(a)*M(c) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & c^\intercal\\ a & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ does not exist in general for $n>2$, since $n^2>4$.

If $n=2$ and $\dim(\text{span}\{ac, ac^\intercal, a^\intercal c, a^\intercal c^\intercal\}) = 4$, there might be a solution for the two equations
$$(j_1k_3+j_3k_7)ac+(j_1k_4+j_3k_8)ac^\intercal+(j_2k_3+j_4k_7)a^\intercal c+(j_2k_4+j_4k_8)a^\intercal c^\intercal = c^\intercal, \\
(j_5k_1+j_5k_5)ac+(j_5k_2+j_7k_6)ac^\intercal+(j_6k_1+j_8k_5)a^\intercal c+(j_6k_2+j_8k_6)a^\intercal c^\intercal = a,$$ over the variables $j_1,\dots, j_8, k_1, \dots, k_8$, but I haven't checked :)

P.S. The reason that this doesn't work in general is because matrix multiplication over $V$ forms a non-abelian group: in general, $ab \neq ba$. The more rigorous nonexistence proof for $n>2$ would probably be a group-theoretic argument. Maybe someone else will chime in!

Comment: The conclusion is that a decomposition $M_1(a) M_2(b) M_3(c)$ is not possible, but a decomposition $M_1^\top (a,c) M_2(b) M_1(a,c)$ does indeed exist.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed but readable answer! I really appreciate it...so I feel bad extending the questions further...but I had also edited my question shortly after posting to specify that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are vectors where $a$ and $b$ have the same dimension. In that case, your initial decomposition wouldn't work under those assumptions.

Could you give me some insight as to what happens when they are all vectors?

Comment: I don't believe your question is properly defined when the entries of your matrix are vectors, since the entries need to have the algebraic structure of a ring. Entries in a matrix need to be from a set $R$ which has two operations: for any $a, b \in R$, $a+b\in R$ and $a * b \in R$. However, the vector products in your question are from $V \times V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Treating the matrix entries as real numbers, $M = \begin{bmatrix}0 & a^\intercal b \\ a^\intercal b & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0 & c^\intercal b \\ c^\intercal b & 0\end{bmatrix}$ is as simple as it gets.